# How to start jupyter notebook in linux sub system of windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

The new update win10 provides a linux(Ubuntu?) sub system in shell.
It is powerful, and faster than virtual OS. It runs everything well except jupyter notebook. 
I've start the service in bash shell of win 10 . The problem is when I enter into by broswer (127.0.0.1：8888 or other port which noticed by jupyter notebook), the the page and the terminal infromation says that kernel in a restarting - stopping circle.
How can I deal with this error?

[image]

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2):

From the [horse's mouth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq):

> WSL does **not** aim to support GUI desktops or applications (e.g. Gnome, KDE, etc.)
>
> Also, even though you will be able to run many popular server applications (e.g. Redis), we do not recommend WSL for server scenarios – Microsoft offers a variety of solutions for running production Ubuntu workloads in Azure, Hyper-V and Docker.

Your error indicates that Jupyter is one of those non-recommended server scenarios. Consider using an actual Linux distro instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) already installs Python and the Jupyter Notebook (and other packages) directly on Windows.